# Set Discount - Three categories, multiple options

Tags: promotions, price

We are trying to set up the following scenario with discounts in our Magento Store, we have tried everything with no luck.

Products:

- Product A - Category A
- Product B - Category B
- Product C - Category C

Desire Discounts:

- Option #1: If a customer has in cart Product A and Product B, apply 5 % discount
  on Product B
- Option #2: If a customer has in cart Product A and Product C, apply
  10 % discount on Product C
- Option #3: If a customer has in cart Product A, Product B and Product C,
  apply 12 % discount on Product B and Product C

Our issue, for example, is that if someone has in cart Two Products A and Three Products B, the discount only applies once, when it should apply twice. (As there are two combos #1)

Any idea how we could solve this?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. The order in which the discounts get processed, I recommend to discount in descending order of the discount. This can be achieved by the priorities.
2. You want all the discounts processed, so don't use the option: "Stop processing after this rule"

And the sentence "our issue, for example" may be interpreted as "there are more problems, then you described" - if there is more, please edit the question.